# How to connect remote IBM QM in java?

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

Friends,
       I want to connect remote IBM QM in java by binding method(JNI). Is it possible?. else
guide me better option for implementing in java.

Comment: Please add more details on your situation. I.E. What are your goals, I would like to do this ... when I connect.  Someone may have another option that is not using IBM QM.

Answer (score 1):

Using bindings mode you can only connect to a queue manager running on the same machine as your application. In bindings mode application and queue manager use shared memory to communicate. As you may be knowing, memory can not be shared across machines.

You should use the client mode connection to communicate with a remote queue manager.